# How to obtain correct L and U matrices from LU decomposition of a sparse matrix A, without using scipy.sparse.linalg.splu()?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-decomposition

I have noticed that `scipy.sparse.linalg.splu()` does not allow me to decompose a sparse matrix A into the correct L and U matrix that I can call separately. The command ''merely'' allows me to decompose the matrix and reconstruct it later on using the permutation matrix. However, for my code I need to decompose a sparse matrix A into a sparse matrix L and U and then be able to call the L and U matrices separately (without permutation matrices etc.). This does not work when using the `scipy.sparse.linalg.splu()` command. I could use `scipy.linalg.lu()` but I cannot apply this to a matrix A in *sparse* format. Are there any other methods out there for obtaining the correct L and U decomposition matrices from a sparse matrix A? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7700) and to [this proposed commit](https://github.com/kevinrichardgreen/scipy/commit/adfa5b8196b106127dd0fa65457263bb6a1f2d69) — do they help?

Comment: @gboffi Oh my god, finally! Finally I've found a fix for this horrific problem. Thank you so much! The first link turned out to contain a simple fix to my problem. I'm not entirely sure what everything means due to inexperience but it'll do for now. Thanks again!

Comment: Be careful (i.e., check that the permutation is `range(...)`) because the issue is about `splu` _sometimes not respecting_ your `'natural'` option.  I think the fix proposed in the commit has not yet been applied to Scipy. Glad to be helpful, ciao

Comment: @gboffi Yeah the poster of the fix already mentioned it was more of a workaround, rather than an actual fix. It worked nicely for my application though. Thanks again!